# Выравнивание массива из int64_t в C

Tags: c

Может ли существовать случай, когда С-компилятор выполнит выравнивание массива из `int64_t`?

Спрашиваю чтобы понять, полностью ли следующий код корректен:

```
/* 
   USAGE: 
   int64_t m = supermax(1, 234234, 35423523, 777); // m = 35423523
*/

#define supermax(...) _supermax((int64_t[]){__VA_ARGS__}, sizeof((int64_t[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(int64_t))
int64_t _supermax(int64_t arr[], int size)
{
    int64_t max = arr[0];

    int i = 0;
    while (i < size) {
        if (arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];
        i++;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Данный код корректный и после предпроцессора код будет таким

```
 int64_t x = _supermax( (int64_t[]){1,2,3,4,5}, sizeof((int64_t[]){1,2,3,4,5})/sizeof(int64_t) );
```

Массив эта не структура , и даже если компилятор как то выравнивает массивы , то для программы это нейтрально.

Comment: А какой компилятор это может скомпилировать? VC++ 2015, например, отказался...

Comment: `gcc --version` 
`gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4`

Comment: макрос с переменым числом парметров `#define x(...)   printf(__VA_ARGS__)` , Появился в стандарте С99

Comment: Да, каюсь, я просто не обратил внимание, что это C, а не C++. Компилируется.

Comment: Спасибо. Мне кажется ещё подойдёт такой ответ:
Компилятор выравнивает до машинного слова. Соответственно, если int64_t не меньше машинного слова, выравнивания не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Для любого массива

```
T array[N];
```

выражение

```
sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])
```

дает количество элементов в массиве, если это вас интересует.

Comment: да, я как раз писал с++сникам за день до вопроса, что это несравнимо красивее чем через шаблон.
`
template<typename T,std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t arraySize(T (&)[N]) noexcept
{
    return N;
}
`